# I need to fill a List with API call's results with Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, api

So I've been trying with many different methods but I can't get around it. Basically this happens:

- API function call returns a Dict inside of a list.
- I have a list of arguments that need to be passed to the function above one by one.
- I don't care about order.
- Last step is to append that list to a Pandas.DataFrame which will remove duplicates and order and etc.
  Examples (btw, the API is Python-Binance):

```
symbols = ['ADAUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']
orders = pd.DataFrame()
for s in symbols:
    orders = orders.append(client.get_all_orders(symbol=s)) # This returns the Dict
```

I tried using Queue() and Thread(), both with Lock(). I tried ThreadPoolExecutor() as well but I cannot make it work. The furthest I reached was with the last method but the amount of lines where different after each execution:

```
orders = pd.DataFrame()
temp = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(get_orders, symbols)

for x in temp:
    orders = orders.append([x])
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the language you are using as a tag to your question.  I think it's Python?

Comment: Correct! I will, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the sidelines, used alone `orders.append([x])`

this can help you

```
from binance import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

symbols = ['ADAUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']

orders_symbol =[]

orders = {}

for s in symbols:

    orders.setdefault(s,{})

    orders_symbol = client.get_all_orders(symbol=s)

    for i in orders_symbol:

        orders[s][i['orderId']] = i

        print (s,i['orderId'],orders[s][i['orderId']])

        print ()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that one and see how it goes